# Binding list of class to a data grid in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, binding, datagrid

I've searched through the various questions about this that have been asked before, but none of them quite seem to fix my issue.  I have a data grid in my wpf app.  Here is the xml:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    ...
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    ...

    <DataGrid
        Name="ReportGrid"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        CanUserAddRows="True"
        IntemsSource="{Binding}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Path=CreateDate}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

And in my project I have this class:

```
Public Class NameData

    Private _CreateDate() As String
    Public Property CreateDate() As String
        Get
            Return _CreateDate
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value as String)
            _CreateDate = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _Name As String
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _Name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value as String)
            _Name = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

And in the code for main window:

```
Private ReportList As New List(Of NameData)
```

I've done bindings like this through code many times, but I've decided that it's time to man up and learn to do the bindings through xml.  When the application runs I'm not getting anything in my datagrid even when I add items to the list.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Based upon what you have posted so far, the binding engine can't find your list because it's private.  Also, it's not clear where the window's context is set.  You'll need to post that code also.  With that, I could give some ideas in c#, but not vb.

Comment: @GayotFow `DataContext` has been set to the Window's code-behind : `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`

Comment: @GayotFow I tried making report list public and setting it up as a property.  har07 is correct about how I've set the data context.  If you have ideas in C# go ahead and shoot.  I don't use it on a regular basis, but I'm familiar enough with it and the .net environment that I can translate it.  If something works out I'll amend my question with the VB version of whatever you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

As also suggested by @GayotFlow in comment, binding engine only work with public property. Try to change definition of `ReportList` to a public property :

```
Private _ReportList As New List(Of NameData)
Public Property ReportList() As List(Of NameData)
    Get
        Return _ReportList
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value as List(Of NameData))
        _ReportList = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Then in XAML, bind the `DataGrid`'s `ItemsSource` to `ReportList` :

```
<DataGrid
    Name="ReportGrid"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    CanUserAddRows="True"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ReportList}">
    ........
    ........
</DataGrid>
```

Note: If `ReportList` items can change at run-time, it is advisable to use `ObservableCollection` instead of `List` because the former has built in mechanism to notify UI to refresh whenever items added to or removed from collection.

Comment: Sorry, no dice on this one.  Even after adjusting my procedure to add items to the list by passing a list back and forth through the property.  Still not there just yet.  Thanks for the suggestions though, and I'll check out `ObservableCollection` in the future.